# TOSHIBA Satellite L505D Bios password reset procedures

Tags: toshiba-laptop

TOSHIBA Satellite L505D
Located the jumper/shorting terminals, shorting procedure did not work.
Located the backup battery it is soldered. Has anyone confirmed temporarily disconnecting the backup battery will resolve my failed Bios reset attempts?

Comment: Did you remove the RAM before you did this? Ive Read in some cases removing the Ram then shorting the pins work. But in Theory from a lot of post on the Net. Cutting the wire and resetting will work. You can either cut it and the connect it back together or unsolder one side reset it then solder it back. Soldering would be the best choice.

Comment: Hi yes removed both RAM cards. Repeated steps multiple times still no BIOS reset?

Comment: so did you cut or unsolder one end of the battery?

Comment: This is not exactly about your laptop model but it could probably help you to find your way : [**link**](https://superuser.com/questions/1108228/remove-bios-password-for-hp-probook-4530s-reset-bios)